# CodeIgniter URL security

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, url-encoding

Are URI/URLs escaped in CI when used like so?

```
function foo($url_arg)
$this->input->get('foo');
```

Comment: You can read about your question here [Input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html). Section **Security Filtering**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example contains 2 different types of inputs - a URI segment (the argument passed to `foo()`) and a GET array item named `foo`.

The [URI class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) contains a private method called `_filter_uri` that, as you may have guessed, takes care of filtering the URI. First, it will check the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` item located in `config.php` and remove any character not defined there. Regardless of what is defined there, however, it will also do the following:

```
// Convert programatic characters to entities
$bad = array('$', '(', ')', '%28', '%29');
$good = array('&#36;', '&#40;', '&#41;', '&#40;', '&#41;');
return str_replace($bad, $good, $str);
```

[Check out the URI class source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/URI.php) for more information.

Regarding the GET array item, if `$config['allow_get_array']` (again, located in `config.php`) is set to `FALSE`, the GET array will be completely destroyed. `$this->input->get('foo')`, by default, permits "only alpha-numeric (and a few other) characters". If a 2nd paramater of `TRUE` is included, CodeIgniter will run the value(s) through its XSS filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable csrf protection by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this:

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;